# Why is my Windows 8.1 App GridView applying a random theme to one of the items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a basic hub app and the first thing I am trying to do is layout some GridView items.  However, one of the items has a different style and I can't figure out why.  Why does this one item behave differently?

[image]

I started with the HubView starter project and replaced one of the sections with the following:

```
            <HubSection Width="500" x:Uid="Section1Header" Header="Section 1">
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid >
                    <GridView x:Name="DistrictIconGV" Background="Black">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="155" Width="115" Margin="20,5,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FFFF5F5F">
                                    <Image Height="80" Width="80" Source="{Binding Icon}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="115"/>
                                    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="74,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" RenderTransformOrigin="1.508,0.48" Visibility="{Binding UnreadVisible}">
                                        <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
                                        </Ellipse.Stroke>
                                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="19,30.5" StartPoint="19,0.5" SpreadMethod="Repeat" MappingMode="Absolute">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF9C5C5" Offset="0.253"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.677"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                                    </Ellipse>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="69,4,11,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UnreadCount}" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="16" Visibility="{Binding UnreadVisible}" Foreground="Black"/>

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <!-- This data is only for testing the layout, it will be overriden at run time-->
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Blitzen" UnreadCount="33"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Comet"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Cupid"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Dasher"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Dancer"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Donner"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Vixen"/>
                        <local:IconListItem IconSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Name="Prancer"/>
                    </GridView>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it selected? If you click another one does it change?

Comment: If I click the item right above it will change for about a second and looks like I would expect, otherwise it stays darker than the rest, even if selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, it was a weird one.   Any item following one where the ellipse is visible changes style for some reason.  If I replace the ellipse in the item template with the ellipse below the problem disappears.

```
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="74,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" RenderTransformOrigin="1.508,0.48" Visibility="{Binding UnreadVisible}">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF94141" Opacity="0.8"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
```